# rails docker app bundle rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I'm trying to create a Rails app using docker and am getting an error during my initial `docker build`.  I've been following various tutorials to try to get this to work, but am not having any luck.

**My error:**

```
Step 10/12 : RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/neo SECRET_TOKEN=foobar assets:precompile
 ---> Running in d3d282e3eb8b
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
/app/config/application.rb:57:in `<class:Application>'
/app/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:NeoDocker>'
/app/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:5:in `require_relative'
/app/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command '/bin/sh -c bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/neo SECRET_TOKEN=foobar assets:precompile' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends \
      build-essential nodejs libpq-dev
ENV INSTALL_PATH /app
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install --binstubs
COPY . .
RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/neo SECRET_TOKEN=foobar assets:precompile
VOLUME ["$INSTALL_PATH/public"]
CMD puma -C config/puma.rb
```

My Gemfile is pretty much the default for Rails 5 now:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'rack-timeout', '~> 0.4'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'redis-rails', '~> 5.0.0.pre'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 4.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.7'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 0.10'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you solve your problem but maybe the answer help someone

The warning you can try solving updating Rails in your Gemfile, changing:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
```

by

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
```

and then execute `bundle update rails` (I don't know if in Docker is necesary)

Also maybe you can have an error in your `/app/config/application.rb` file in line 57

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution. 
`https://github.com/giapnhdev/rails-base`
It includes some awesome gems for your project like:
`devise, seed_fu, shrine,...`